# UWP ListView PointerEntered

Tags: uwp

Is there anyway to get index of ListViewElement I had my pointerover?

With SelectionChanged it's easy, I use

```
int index = MyListView.SelectedIndex;
```

But how am I supposed to get index of last element my cursor was over?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.tooltipservice.tooltipproperty?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ToolTipService_ToolTipProperty) and [data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#binding-to-a-collection-of-items) to do this. In the following sample, ToolTip is bound to the `index` property of the `Fruit` class. When you hover over the ListViewItem, ToopTip will display the index.

If you want to use the index of last element your cursor was over, you could use the global variable ***pointIndex*** in the example. When the pointEnter event is triggered, you could use the DataContext of the current textBlock to get the index property of data source. Please refer to the `TextBlock_PointerEntered` event in the sample.

XAML code:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fruits}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding index}" PointerEntered="TextBlock_PointerEntered"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
namespace TestDemo
{    
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public int pointIndex;
        public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>()
            {
                new Fruit(){name="Apple",index=0},
                new Fruit(){name="Banana",index=1},
                new Fruit(){name="Orange",index=2},
                new Fruit(){name="Cherry",index=3},
                new Fruit(){name="Strawberry",index=4}
            };           
        }
        private void TextBlock_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock t = sender as TextBlock;
            Fruit fruit = t.DataContext as Fruit;
            pointIndex = fruit.index;
        }
    }
    public class Fruit
   {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the question have to do with tooltips? Setting the Tooltip just to get the index is not a good idea.

Comment: @chingucoding ToolTip is just to visually display the current index. To make it easier to see the effect.
My answer said that if you want to use an index, you can use the variable **pointIndex** in my example.

Comment: I see. I don't think it's ideal to inject an index number into the data just for the purpose of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the [PointerEntered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerentered?view=winrt-19041) event and create a new variable that tracks what the index of the last element raising that event was:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind myElements}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding elementName}" PointerEntered="Element_PointerEntered"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

```cs
int lastIndex = -1;

private void Element_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lastIndex = myListView.IndexFromContainer((DependencyObject)sender);
}
```